# Shuffling a pack of $52$ cards repeatedly until the pack is unshuffled

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, card-games

A pack of $52$ playing cards is to be shuffled as follows:

I. Putting the top $7$ cards (one-by-one) on each other on a table. Lets call this group of the $7$ cards GROUP $A$.

II. Putting the top $3$ cards (one-by-one) on each other on the table. Lets call this group of the $3$ cards GROUP $B$.

III. Putting the top $3$ cards (without shuffling them) on the top of GROUP $B$.

IV. Putting the top $7$ cards (one-by-one) on the top of GROUP $A$.

V. Putting the top $3$ cards (one-by-one) on the top of GROUP $B$.

VI. Putting the top $3$ cards (without shuffling them) on the top of GROUP $B$.

VII. Repeating steps IV, V, and VI until all the cards are placed on the table.

VIII. Putting GROUP $A$ on the top of GROUP $B$.

Doing these $8$ steps completes $1$ run of shuffling.

> How many runs do we need to make the $52$ playing cards having the
>   same original order?

Any hint to solve this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: -1 What are your thoughts on the problem? Where did you find this problem? Is this homework? What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Servaes This was asked by my old teacher. It is not a homework, I am just curious how to solve it because I think it is an interesting problem. I have not try anything because I do not know the key of solving it. I am not asking about the answer. Giving any hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to first write the deck shuffling as a permutation in [two-line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Two-line_notation) and then to translate this to cycle notation. With some work you can then reduce this to a product of disjoint cycles, and compute the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles to find the number of shuffles required.

Comment: Can I ask you please to explain that, for this problem? I really tried but I did not get it. Thanks in advance.